# How do I get the cPanel phpAdmin on Godaddy server to connect to the Godaddy server?

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I login to myphpadmin, the title bar shows @localhost. [image]
It should be connecting to the server.
How can I fix this?

When I try to import, I get #1044 - Access denied for user 'npac5kml87yg'@'localhost' to database 'modb'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your phpMyAdmin is being executed by a webserver running on the same system as the database server. The connection *relative to phpMyAdmin* is to localhost; in this case it doesn't matter from where you're accessing it because the connection from the webserver to the database server (which you're seeing here) is separate from the connection from your browser to the webserver (details of which are not reported by phpMyAdmin).

The permissions error indicates that your user doesn't have the proper permissions on the database modb. You should check your permissions or ask your host to grant your user the proper permissions.